# Automatically connecting to a network when the cable is plugged in

Tags: linux, networking, gentoo

Is there a way to have linux connect to the network when the ethernet cable is plugged in? I'm using Gentoo Linux, and I haven't found the right setup for the conf/net that'll allow me to do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Install [ifplugd](http://0pointer.de/lennart/projects/ifplugd/).